# Is it ever appropriate to use finalize() in Java?

Tags: java, android, c++, memory-management

I've got an Android project that heavily uses C++ JNI shared objects.  In fact, I've got a Java object that manages resources allocated from JNI calls.  On that particular Java object, I'm using a finalize() call to handle the freeing of those native resources when the object gets destroyed.

This all seems to work and I don't see any memory leaks, however, I've heard that you using Java finalizers is frowned upon (Effective java, 2nd edition page 27. Item 7: Avoid finalizers, etc.).  Are there cases, such as the one I've described above, where using finalize() is appropriate?  I'm not sure what else to do to ensure that those native resources get cleaned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your case is one of the few where it's [appropriate to use a finalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29).

Comment: @bstar55 it should be the first.

Comment: @bstar55 there is no code that can convey convention as to when said code should be used.  In the case of Javadoc, the doc is part of the code so if you had looked through the code you would have found the documentation regardless.